# Perl - Match multiline pattern with wildcard

Tags: regex, perl

I have this example file test.txt:

```
aba
aca

ada

bcd
baa
```

I would like to find every occurence where a line starting with `a` and ending with `a` is followed by another such line. However, my attempts are futile:

```sh
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /(a.*a/n)/sg' test.txt 
(...) # Matches the whole file as it starts with "a" and ends with "a\n"
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /(a.*?a\n)/sg' test.txt # What is this even
aba

aca

ada

aa
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /(a.*a\n){2}/sg' test.txt
aca

ada

bcd
baa

perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /(a.*?a\n){2}/sg' test.txt
aca
```

These are my results on OSX. Can someone help me out here with the desired pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `/s`, so you can actually match lines. Also, add `^` and `$` with `/m` to match line starts and ends:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /^(a.*a)\n(a.*a)$/mg'
```

Or, process line by line remembering the previous line if it matches.

```
perl -lne '($q) = /^(a.*a)$/; print $p if $p && $q; $p = $q'
```

Note that the two solutions differ in how they treat more than two `a.*a` lines occurring sequentially. See ikegami's comment for an alternative solution.

Comment: It prints the correct line, but why is this one different?
```perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /^((a.*a)\n){2}$/mg' test.txt
aca
```

Comment: @ÁdámHunyadi: Because quantified capture group returns only the last match, i.e. the second line in this case.

Comment: Note that your two solutions aren't equivalent. The first doesn't meet the spec in situations where there are more than two matching lines in a row. (Using `/^(a.*a)\n(?=a.*a)$/` instead of `/^(a.*a)\n(a.*a)$/` would fix that.)